# plot line graph using jquery-ajax

Tags: plot, json

i've created an application for drawing a line graph using **plot plugin**.
i've created a json array using java `JSONObject` class and passed to jquery-ajax, but while importing the json to $plot() function, i'm getting no line graph drawn.

can anyone please tell me some solution for this

my **javascript** is this

```
var options = {};
var placeholder = $("#placeholder1");

$.ajax({
url : "getDashboardvalue.action",
dataType : "application/json",
type : "POST",
data : {
    operation : "custyear"
},
success : function(data) {
var plot = $.plot(placeholder, data, options);  
}
});
```

my **struts2.xml**

```
<action name="getDashboardvalue" class="commonpackage.Graphclass" method="getDashboardvalue">
</action>
```

inside my my **Graphclass.java**

```
public void getDashboardvalue() throws IOException
    {
        try{
        HttpServletResponse response = (HttpServletResponse) ActionContext.getContext().get(org.apache.struts2.StrutsStatics.HTTP_RESPONSE);
        HttpServletRequest  request  = (HttpServletRequest) ActionContext.getContext().get(org.apache.struts2.StrutsStatics.HTTP_REQUEST);

        System.out.println("operation-------------->"+operation); 
        if(operation.equals("custyear"))
        {
        JSONObject jsonObj = new JSONObject(
"{ label: \'Development\', data: [[1,53914],[2,32172],[3,825],[4,838],[5,756],[6,50877],[7,0], [8,0],[9,0],[10,0],[11,0],[12,0]]}");

        System.out.println(jsonObj.toString());

        response.setContentType("application/json");
        response.getWriter().write(jsonObj.toString());

        }
        }catch(Exception e){
            System.out.println("Exception:"+e);
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
```

when i put the json directly like as shown below i'm getting the graph

```
var data =[
{ label:"Development", data: [[1,53914],[2,32172],[3,825],[4,838],[5,756],[6,50877],[7,0], [8,0],[9,0],[10,0],[11,0],[12,0]] }
          }

var options = {};

var placeholder = $("#placeholder1");

var plot = $.plot(placeholder, data, options);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this

```
var options = {};
var placeholder = $("#placeholder1");

$.ajax({
url : "getDashboardvalue.action",
dataType : "json",
type : "POST",
data : {
    operation : "custyear"
},
success : function(data) {
var plot = $.plot(placeholder, [data], options);  
}
});
```